# formulating a sequence (requesting a formula for a simple sequence)

Tags: calculus

How to represent the sequence
$$-1,2,3,-4,-5,-6,7,8,9,10,-11,-12,-13,-14,-15, \dots$$
with a formula?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $d(n) = k$ such that $ \dfrac{(k-1)k}{2} < n \leq \dfrac{k(k+1)}{2}$

Then your sequence is
$$(-1)^{d(n)}n$$